# Generating incremental ID for xml attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XSL.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:element name="root">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ModelDefinition/ContainerSpecNode"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="ContainerSpecNode">
            <xsl:element name="item">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@specId"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="pathId"><xsl:value-of select="@pathId"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="specId"><xsl:value-of select="@specId"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="rel"><xsl:value-of select="@specType"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="content">
                    <xsl:element name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="shortName"/>
                        <xsl:if test="(@minimumCardinalityCount = '0') or (@maximumCardinalityCount != '1')"> [<xsl:value-of select="@minimumCardinalityCount"/>..<xsl:value-of select="@maximumCardinalityCount"/>]</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="propertySpecs/PropertySpecNode">
                    <xsl:sort select="shortName"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I want to create create incremental unique number for ID attributes of Item element for each containerSpecNode just like "Tree_node_1" , "Tree_Node_2" and so on... Here I modified code like this.

```
. . . . . .
<xsl:element name="item">
<xsl:variable name="count">
            <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="'Tree_Node_'"/><xsl:value-of select="$count+1"/></xsl:attribute>
```

It increments count value but not for all ContainerSpecNode. Some ID have duplicate value.

I want create for each ContainerSpecNode. How can i do this.
Can I use for-each loop? and How?

Comment: You forgot to show us the source XML document on which this transformation is applied. The transformation can be written much shorter and more readable -- if we had also the source XML. Please, edit the question and add this important information.

Comment: I have added my source XML. Please check .

Comment: The XML that was "added" is nowhere to be seen ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are close to a correct solution**.

**Just replace**:

```
<xsl:variable name="count">             
  <xsl:number/>             
</xsl:variable>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select=
     "count(preceding::ContainerSpecNode | ancestor::ContainerSpecNode) +1"/>
```

Comment: I was wondering how this will work . Have tried this but not working. By looking observing my source XML you may come to know containerSpecNode can have child container as containerSpecode which can have child container further.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre for your answer. It worked. Since I have less experience in XSLT , can you please elaborate more on working of preceding and ancestor with OR operator in your answer. Although my problems is solved by your answer I want to know how this code is doing job.

Comment: @RaghuvirSingh: You are welcome (it would be good if you accept the answer -- by clicking the check-mark next to it). As for your question, `|` is not "or" -- it is the XPath *union* operator. As its name implies the union operator produces the (set) union of two node-sets. It has exactly the same semantics as **U** (union) in set-theory. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-UnionExpr